# delete a row from table and database on clicking checkbox using jsp

Tags: jsp

Here id of the table is passed from the delete button. But I could not delete the record from database and table. Here's the code:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {        

        try {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);

                var did;

                id=request.getParameter("check"+i);
                out.println(did);
                }

                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }


  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jspdatabase","root", "kca@fnpl#12");
 st=con.createStatement();

  st.executeUpdate("delete from table1 where id ='"+did+"'");
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete"onclick="deleteRow(tableID)" /> control didnt pass to the function function deleteRow(tableID)

Comment: Although I am not providing your solution here but one thing to point out, I am sure you must be using JDBC 4.0 or above so try not to explicitly writing Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); another thing use try-with-resource.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems to me like you are never setting variable "did" to any value.

```
var did;
id=request.getParameter("check"+i);
```

Should be

```
var did;
did=request.getParameter("check"+i);
```

Also, you should declare var did outside the function (at the very top) so that it still exists outside of the function.